# ¿Agrupar propiedades iguales de objeto js?

Tags: javascript

Quisiera saber como agrupar por nombre y su vez poder sumar el total de este objeto

```
[{brand_name: "Romance", total: 36577},
 {brand_name: "Daytona", total: 18260},
 {brand_name: "Romance", total: 31467},
 {brand_name: "Testzoid", total: 17580},
 {brand_name: "Testzoid", total: 16900},
 {brand_name: "Angora", total: 28246},
 {brand_name: "Angora", total: 37307},
 {brand_name: "Ravish", total: 22415}]
```

lo que quiero es agruparlo de esta forma

```
[{brand_name: "Romance", total: (total_romance)},
 {brand_name: "Daytona", total: (total_daytona)},
 {brand_name: "Testzoid", total: (totaltestzoid)},
 {brand_name: "Angora", total: (total_angora)},
 {brand_name: "Ravish", total: (total_ravish)}]
```

que quede por marca y que sume los totales de cada marca es decir el total de "Romance" + el total de "Romance" en un obj

he intentado esto para conseguir el primer objeto mencionado

```
function calculateTotal(data) {
  let total = [];

  for (const item of data) {
     const op1 = item.price * item.seller_commission_percent;
     const 0p2 = item.price * 0.12;
     const op3 = item.price - op1 - op2 - item.logistic_cost;

     total.push({
        brand_name: item.brand_name,
        total: parseInt(three)
     });
   }

   return total;
}

let calculo = calculateTotal(data);
console.log(calculo);
```

Answer (score 3):

Yo agruparía con `.reduce` y después lo transformaría al tipo de array que quieres obtener:

```js
const obj = [{brand_name: "Romance", total: 36577},
{brand_name: "Daytona", total: 18260},
{brand_name: "Romance", total: 31467},
{brand_name: "Testzoid", total: 17580},
{brand_name: "Testzoid", total: 16900},
{brand_name: "Angora", total: 28246},
{brand_name: "Angora", total: 37307},
{brand_name: "Ravish", total: 22415}];


const resumen = obj.reduce((p,c)=>{ // <-- primero agrupamos 
    p[c.brand_name] = (p[c.brand_name]  || 0)+c.total;
    return p;
},{})

const resultado = Object.keys(resumen).map(e=>{ // <-- después transformamos el formato
    const o = {};
    o.brand_name = e;
    o.total = resumen[e];
    return o;
})


console.log(resultado);
```

La parte interna del `.reduce` es una forma reducida de:

```
const resumen = obj.reduce((p,c)=>{
    if(c.brand_name in p){
        p[c.brand_name] += c.total;//<-- si ya existe le sumamos el total
    }else{
        p[c.brand_name] = c.total;//<-- si no existe le asignamos el total
    }
    return p;
},{});
```

`resumen` entonces da como resultado:

```
{
  Romance: 68044,
  Daytona: 18260,
  Testzoid: 34480,
  Angora: 65553,
  Ravish: 22415
}
```

Lo que hacemos después es simplemente transformarlo en un array de objetos con las propiedades que requieres.

Comment: me sirve tu respuesta pero si te fijas estas sumando tambien los que no estan repetidos por ejemplo "Ravish" da como total 44830 cuando deberia mantener el mismo total que ya era 22415

Comment: Tienes razón, hay que comparar con p.

Comment: @Emmeus podrias explicarme de que manera comparas usando reducer para asi evitar que se sumen si no existen mas de dos

Comment: @Rafael `reduce` arranca con el tipo de dato que le pasas como segundo parámetro, en este caso un objeto vacío {}. Lo que hacemos es decir existe la propiedad y el valor de esa marca, sino cero. Eso lo hacemos con `(p[c.brand_name]  || 0)` a eso le sumamos el total de la marca. Si la propiedad no existe la vamos a agregar también. Es decir que el objeto `resumen` va a quedar algo así`{
  Romance: 68044,
  Daytona: 18260,
  Testzoid: 34480,
  Angora: 65553,
  Ravish: 22415
}`

Answer (score 0):

para poder hacer esto, donde, se pregunta si tiene la propiedad, para acumular el total en caso contrario solo se le asigna para pasar al siguiente brand_name, y al final te retorna como un objeto, también puedes hacerlo por array.

```js
const grupos = [
  {brand_name: "Romance", total: 36577},
  {brand_name: "Daytona", total: 18260},
  {brand_name: "Romance", total: 31467},
  {brand_name: "Testzoid", total: 17580},
  {brand_name: "Testzoid", total: 16900},
  {brand_name: "Angora", total: 28246},
  {brand_name: "Angora", total: 37307},
  {brand_name: "Ravish", total: 22415}
]

const gruposSumados = grupos.reduce((c, {brand_name, total}) => {
   if (c.hasOwnProperty(brand_name)) {
     c[brand_name] += total
   } else {
     c[brand_name] = total
   }
  return c
}, {})

console.log(gruposSumados)
```